# How to Handle Simultaneous Requests for JavaScript Booking System on SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am creating a JavaScript application on SharePoint and am having issues with users hitting the submit button at the exact same time for a booking slot. If there is a few second difference, my checking function only allows the first user the booking, but if it is at the same time, the checking function does not get the updated data in time and the person who clicked submit a few milliseconds slower actually gets the slot.

**How do I create some kind of lock to prevent the booking overwrite?**

My current implementation is using a SharePoint list as a substitute database and recording the data for bookings on there.

When the submit button is clicked, the following function is called:

```
function checkIfAlreadyBooked() {
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var queryString = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Start_x0020_Time' /><Value Type='Text'>" + startTimeValue + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(queryString);
    listContext2 = new SP.ClientContext(url);
    list2 = listContext2.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Massage Bookings");
    listItem2 = list2.getItems(camlQuery);
    listContext2.load(listItem2);

    listContext2.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        OnCheckBookedSuccess(submitData);
    }, OnCheckBookedFailure);
}
```

The function above loads the context for the SharePoint list and retrieves the item being clicked, then goes to the success function OnCheckBookedSuccess:

```
function OnCheckBookedSuccess(callback) {
    var listItemEnumerator = listItem2.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        if (oListItem.get_item("Status") == "Booked") {
            callback(true);
        }
        else {
            callback(false);
        }
    }
}
```

The above function is used to take the list item and check whether it is already booked or not, returning true or false to the callback function submitData:

```
function submitData(booked) {
    var bookingFormSection = document.getElementById("bookingFormSection");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var queryString = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Start_x0020_Time' /><Value Type='Text'>" + startTimeValue + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(queryString);
    listItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    if (!booked) {
        if (checkIfDataValid()) {
            listContext.load(listItem);
            listContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSubmitSuccess, OnSubmitFailure);
        }
    }
    else {
        var message = document.createElement("label");
        message.style.color = "Red";
        message.setAttribute("class", "sessionBookedLabel");
        message.innerHTML = "This session has already been booked.";
        if (!bookingFormSection.getElementsByClassName("sessionBookedLabel")[0]) {
            bookingFormSection.appendChild(message);
        }
    }
}
```

The above function uses booked as the true/false returned from the callback and gives an error message if already booked, or creates the booking using OnSubmitSuccess if not booked:

```
function OnSubmitSuccess(sender, args) {
    var lName = document.getElementById("lName").value;
    var fName = document.getElementById("fName").value;
    var phoneNum = document.getElementById("phoneNum").value;
    var startTime = document.getElementById("startTime").value;

    lName = lName.trim();
    fName = fName.trim();
    lName = lName.toLowerCase();
    fName = fName.toLowerCase();

    var listItemEnumerator = listItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        oListItem.set_item("Title", lName);
        oListItem.set_item("First_x0020_Name", fName);
        oListItem.set_item("Phone_x0020_Number", phoneNum);
        oListItem.set_item("Status", "Booked");
        oListItem.update();
    } 

    navigateHome();
}
```

The above function modifies the list item with the booking data for the SharePoint list.

Answer (score 0):

We can create two field "CheckInOut" type to be "Choice field"(contain "Check-in" and Check-Out) and "CheckedOutTo" and type to be "Single line of text".

When update the list item before, set "CheckInOut" to "Check-Out" and "CheckOutTo" to current user, then check if "CheckInOut" is Check-Out and "CheckOutTo" is current user.

Here is a blog for your reference.

[Check-in and Check-out Functionality For Custom List Items in SharePoint 2013 Using jQuery](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0e18a8/check-in-and-check-out-functionality-for-custom-list-items-i/)

Comment: But how would you implement this without running into the same problem? If two people try to checkout the list item at the same time (by clicking a button or ticking a radio button) wouldn't the same issue occur? I have also considered doing this and possibly using timestamps, but waiting for the data to be written to the SharePoint list would make the checks still not properly deny 1 user.

Comment: The CheckOutTo field only allow set one user, before the current user to submit, check this field whether is current user, if not, don't allow update.

Comment: Yes, I know it only allows one user. But let's say I have it set so if the button is clicked, it sets the user to the field. If two people click at the same time, the person slower by a few milliseconds will overwrite the data in field so that the first person does not get it right?

Comment: You can use javascript setTimeout method to wait 5 seconds to query the values, then run other code.

Comment: Where in the above would I put the setTimeout? Because I tried a setTimeout before and it had no difference because it just adds the same amount of processing time to both instances of the script action. This makes it have the same issue as when I had no setTimeout.